# Xamarin - AutoMapper add profile after Initialize

Tags: c#, xamarin, automapper

I have a Xamarin application that uses Automapper but I have lots of `profiles`.

If I try to load all these `profiles` at the application Init, its take several seconds.

I would like to Initialize the mapper with some base profiles, then when I need others, I would like to add these to the main configuration.

```
public static MapperConfiguration InitAutoMapper()
{
    MapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();

        cfg.AddProfile<BaseProfile>();
        cfg.AddProfile<ComboProfile>();
    });

    return mapperConfiguration;
}

public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    public MyViewModel() {
        // How can I add here the "MyViewModelProfile" to mapperConfiguration?
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

[Link](https://ufile.io/8myek) with profiles and resolvers used.

Comment: That's not possible. You need to find out where that time is spent and then maybe we can do smth about it.

Comment: I have added a Zip that contains Profiles and Resolvers that I use.

Comment: I don't use Xamarin, so I don't think that would help. Unless the code behaves the same on .Net or on .Net Core.